# Grid view rowUpdate and rowcancel event are not working

Tags: c#, gridview, viewstate

I have simple problem. if i make EnableViewState="true" then my onrowediting event works but onrowupdating and onrowcancelingedit do not work.

So I make EnableViewState="false" and in onload grid on every event. therefore, I am loading the grid twise for every event call. that is working fine but makes slower?

is there any way to EnableViewState="true" and onrowupdating and onrowcancelingedit events will work?

Please see my templefield column for editing rows:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <!--To fire the OnRowEditing event.-->
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imbEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit-icon-small.gif" ToolTip="Edit Row" 
                                        Text="Edit" Visible ="false" />

                                </ItemTemplate>

                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                   <!--To fire the OnRowUpdating event.-->
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imbUpdate" CssClass="grid-button-margin" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/images/save.png" ToolTip="Save"
                                        Text="Update" Visible ="false" CausesValidation="true"  ValidationGroup = '<%# Eval("Name") + "_" + Eval("UserID") %>'  />

                                    <!--To fire the OnRowDeleting event.-->
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imbCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" ToolTip="Cancel Edit"
                                        Text="Delete" Visible ="false" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: try to change `CausesValidation` true to false In RowUpdating event..see what happen?